# Calling a .jar with parameters from batch script, with a wildcard in the path

Tags: batch-file, cmd, jar

Trying to call a -jar, with parameters, with a wildcard in the path, using a batch script.  I can do this if I manually enter it into the CMD like this:

```
for /d %a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\*") do "%~fa\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\squirrel-sql-3.7.1-standard.jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\silent3.7.xml
```

I know why that doesn't work in a batch script, I need to add extra '%'s, as shown here:

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\*") do "%%~fa\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\squirrel-sql-3.7.1-standard.jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\silent3.7.xml
```

Problem is, when I try that, the output from the CMD line omits the d in the '/d' at the beginning.  Not sure why this is, not sure what I need to change.  Output from the revised script looks like this:

```
for / %a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\*") do "%~fa\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\squirrel-sql-3.7.1-standard.jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\silent3.7.xml
```

When I manually enter the command (with the single '%'s), I get output that starts like this:

```
C:\windows\system32>for /d %a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\*") do "%~fa\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\squirrel-sql-3.7.1-standard.jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\silent3.7.xml

C:\windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\squirrel-sql-3.7.1-standard.jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\silent3.7.xml

[ Starting automated installation ]
Read pack list from xml definition.
Try to add to selection [Name: Base and Index: 0]
Try to add to selection [Name: Standard and Index: 1]
Try to remove from selection [Name: Optional Plugin - Greenplum and     Index: 2]
Try to remove from selection [Name: Optional Plugin - WIKI table configurations
```

Comment: But the code still executes correctly, so I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: hm, when I run it in my batch, it just outputs that last line and advances, without actually running the command

Comment: I have a feeling you are not showing us something else within the batch file or you did not change it correctly to run in a batch file.  For it to not run in the batch file after doubling the percent symbols for the `FOR` variables is nearly impossible.

Comment: The script is a direct copy/paste, I didn't even sub in <path> or anything like that.  Whatever the issue is, it has something to do with 'for /d' running as 'for /'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually gave up on this, was able to make it work via powershell with this command:

```
start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\*\bin\java.exe" -Argumentlist '-jar',  'C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\squirrel-sql-3.7.1-standard.jar', 'C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\silent3.7.xml'
```

Comment: There was nothing wrong with your batch file syntax if this is truly what you were using. `for /d %%a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\*") do "%%~fa\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\squirrel-sql-3.7.1-standard.jar C:\DTS\BMC\3.7.1\silent3.7.xml`. If you are going to answer this with your powershell code then it pretty much nullifies your question and it should be deleted because the question is batch and the answer is powershell.

Comment: I replied to your earlier comment and added the output to my question.  Regardless of how valid you think my batch script was, the output shows that it wasn't working.